# does anybody know this light-blue emacs theme's name?

Tags: themes, colors

emmm. 
i just found through all the MELPA by keywords theme,
but still cant find this theme, if someone can point out,
i'll appreciate a lot, i love this theme very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like GIthub Modern (https://emacsthemes.com/themes/github-modern-theme.html) or Grey Matters (https://emacsthemes.com/themes/greymatters-theme.html). Check the other light themes at https://emacsthemes.com/tags/light/1.html

Comment: Thanks , I already found the answer by sending email to the unloader of the two pics, this theme only can be found in his github, just a fork and tweak of sunburn, lol

Comment: Great! You can answer your own question then, and explain how to load the theme from github, that would be useful for someone else.

Comment: yes~i answered ,lol.

Answer (score 1):

this theme is in a github repo (https://github.com/chrisdone/zenburn)  and not in the MELPA

and can be loaded in Emacs by the following code

```
(autoload 'sunburn "sunburn")
(sunburn)
```